# fscanf format with integers and characters

Tags: c

I have to read a file and get the fractions (numerators, denominators and the math sign)
Here is the input file:

> 1\4 + 1\3
>   2\5 - 6\13

Part of my code:

```
int numer1[100], numer2[100], denom1[100], denom2[100];
char ope[100];
do{
    checkScan = fscanf(fin, "%d %d %s %d %d", &numer1[line], &denom1[line], &ope[line], &numer2[line], &denom2[line]);
    printf("%d %d %s %d %d\n", numer1[line], denom1[line], ope[line], numer2[line], denom2[line]);
    if(checkScan==EOF){
        printf("End of file\n");
        break;
    }
    if(checkScan!=5){
        printf("Not enough data or invalid data\n");
    }
    line++;
}while(1);
```

Comment: What is the problem? You haven't stated that. You have only pasted code and written that it relates to fscanf, integers and characters. You need to be more explicit about what you are having trouble with, otherwise it is hard to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
checkScan = fscanf(fin, "%d %d %s %d %d", &numer1[line], &denom1[line], &ope[line], &numer2[line], &denom2[line]);
```

by

```
checkScan = fscanf(fin, "%d\\%d %c %d\\%d", &numer1[line], &denom1[line], &ope[line], &numer2[line], &denom2[line]);
```

additional remarks :

- you also need to do the printf only when `checkScan==5` else you do not know what you print
- you also need to increment *line* only when the input is ok
- you need to check *line* is < 100
- if the input string doesn't follow the pattern you will loop indefinitely. I encourage you to first read the line then to parse it.

Cumulating all my remarks :

```
char readLine[100];
int numer1[100], numer2[100], denom1[100], denom2[100];
char ope[100];

while (fgets(readLine, sizeof(readLine), fin)) {
  int checkScan = sscanf(readLine, "%d\\%d %c %d\\%d", &numer1[line], &denom1[line], &ope[line], &numer2[line], &denom2[line]);

  if(checkScan!=5){
    printf("Not enough data or invalid data\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("%d %d %c %d %d\n", numer1[line], denom1[line], ope[line], numer2[line], denom2[line]);
    if (++line == 100)
      break;
  }
}
```

---

note : it is strange to use \ rather than / for a fraction

Comment: would it be better if I first count the number of lines in the file, then initialize the arrays?

Comment: @IcedLemonTea_ yes, or malloc the vector and realloc them when too small

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid format in **scanf**.

**ope** is char type, but in **scanf** you require a c string (char*).

If you want to read a signle char, you should use **%c** as format parameter for scanf:

```c
checkScan = fscanf(fin, "%d %d %c %d %d", &numer1[line], &denom1[line], &ope[line], &numer2[line], &denom2[line]);
```

Comment: “ope is char type” — no it isn’t. However, `ope[line]` is.